# RabbitMQ Consumer Reconnecting

Tags: rabbitmq

Here's the scenario:

Consumer (C) is listening for messages on Queue (Q) and Publisher (P) publishes messages to Q. While C is waiting for messages to be put on Q, Q gets deleted, then P publishes a message, thus Q is recreated with a new message. The issue is that C now doesn't get this message, even though the Q it was listening on has been recreated.

Is there a way to get the Consumer to "reconnect" with the "new" Queue after it's been deleted and recreated? I noticed too that when Q gets deleted, C still listens as if nothing's happened.

Comment: Actually it looks like this (http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-cancel.html) is what I was looking for

Comment: Any reason why the queue is being deleted?  I'm not a rabbitmq expert but the way my devs use rabbitmq on the apps at work, the queue continues to exist even if it's empty.

Comment: I deleted it purely for testing purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your consumer, "C" can [catch connection-related failures](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html). You can then configure "C" to attempt to reconnect at regular intervals, every X seconds after such an event has been caught. Once reconnected, "C" will resume consuming messages from "Q".